# Jest getByText randomly ignoring some text content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm building a survey app in React and using Jest to write my unit tests. Today I made a few changes to some of the question prompts, after which I updated my tests to match. While they were working perfectly with the previous version of the survey, for some reason now `screen.getByText` is ignoring text that is very obviously visible:

```
import { prompts } from "../../data"
// ... Other stuff imported ...

// ... Set up mock spies and other variables ...

test("test case: q1 (y) -> q2 (y) -> q3 (n) -> contact us", async () => {

        // An initial request is made to server to determine survey status
        await act(async () => {
            render(<Survey />)
            const returnedItem = {
                "status": "success",
                "id": testID,
                "surveyStatus": "sent"
            }
            getSpy.mockReturnValue(returnedItem)
        })

        await act(async () => {
            const updateReturnedItem = {
                "status": "success"
            }
            updateSpy.mockReturnValue(updateReturnedItem)
            userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", {name: "Begin"}))
        })

        expect(screen.getByText(prompts["q1"]))
        
        act(() => {
            userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("radio", {name: "Yes"}))
        })

        // Each time a new question is answered, fetch to the DB to update it
        await act(async () => {
            const updateReturnedItem = {
                "status": "success"
            }
            updateSpy.mockReturnValue(updateReturnedItem)
            userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", {name: "Next"}))
        })

        expect(screen.getByText(prompts["q2"]))

        act(() => {
            userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("radio", {name: "Yes"}))
        })

        await act(async() => {
            const updateReturnedItem = {
                "status": "success"
            }
            updateSpy.mockReturnValue(updateReturnedItem)
            userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", {name: "Next"}))
        })

        expect(screen.getByText(prompts["q3"]))

        act(() => {
            userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("radio", {name: "No"}))
        })

        await act(async () => {
            const returnedItem = {
                "status": "success"
            }
            submitSpy.mockReturnValue(returnedItem)
            userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", {name: "Next"}))
        })
        
        expect(screen.getByText(prompts["contactUs"])) // Test fails here
        expect(submitSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(testID, answers)
    })
```

This all passes until the second to last line, where the tests expects to fine the prompt for the contact us page (this is one of the prompts that changed). The weird part is, when the test fails, this is the error that gets spit back out at me:

```
 ● Test survey response possibilities › test case: q1 (y) -> q2 (y) -> q3 (n) -> contact us

    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Thank you. 
Please contact us with further questions.. This could be because the text is broken up by 
multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make 
your matcher more flexible.

    <body>
      <div>
        <div
          class="survey-container"
        >
          <div
            class="survey"
          >
            <p>
              Thank you. Please contact us with further questions.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div
            class="progress"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Clearly the prompt is being rendered correctly as it's shown right there in the returned HTML body. I've also tested it manually and know that it works as intended. I'm confused because this was not a problem up until I tweaked the prompt copy, and even then, other prompts that I also changed today are passing the tests just fine.

Any idea what's going on?

EDIT: To add to the confusion, when I give that p tag a `data-testid` value and then run the tests looking for that, it passes fine. No idea why it can't see text that is clearly being rendered there.

Comment: When looking at the documentation at https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#textmatch it appears to me that the text must be an _exact_ match. As your case is a substring, it looks like you need to add an `options` object as `{ exact: false }`, as in `expect(screen.getByText(prompts["q1"]), { exact: false })`.

Comment: @76484 tried that too and no luck unfortunately. Guess I'll just stick with the `testid` fix for now. Thank you though

Comment: I'd recommend checking for the actual hard coded text instead of via an array. This would make the tests much easier to read for other devs too.

Comment: Hey, op, did you find out what was the problem?